# Preventing access to a public url in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, .net-3.5

I have an asp.net mvc action that I must expose publicly.  The URL is something like:

`http://www.abc.com/controller/action?q="abcdef"`

The `"abcdef"` part is something I will provide to the user who is supposed to access the URL, but that does not prevent someone else from using the same URL, so are there any extra layers of security where I can verify who is using the URL?  Are there any best practices for adding extra info that someone easily can't use or determine unless they are explicitly told that would make the public URL more difficult to use?

Comment: Are we answer you question?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to generate a one-time key, like a GUID, that's only valid for 5 minutes. Store these in your DB, and when someone wants to access the URL with the key, verify that it's been less than 5 minutes ago. You could also verify IP address and/or user agent, but it's no guarantee (neither is the GUID, but it's a good start). You'd also probably want to use HTTPS to avoid people sniffing your keys.

Comment: I was thinking about an IP Filter attribute as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Basic authentication
2. Digest authentication
3. Forms authentication
4. Windows authentication
5. OpenID authentication

Will help you to achieve what you want. They developed as part of HTTP protocol to give you choice. Don't make bicycle some self. The question is to wide. Probably the basic auth is the most simple and fast approach to help you achieve what you want. And please set tags next time to know which technology you use and which server.